# Evaluating a Surface Integral with help of Stoke's Theorem

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Evaluate $\displaystyle \int\int \vec{F}.ds$ where $\vec{F}= -x\hat{i} + 2y\hat{j} -z\hat{k}$ and $S$ is the portion of the $y = 3x^2 + 3z^2$ that lies behind $y =6$ oriented positive $y -axis$ direction.

Now, Using Stoke's theorem this surface integral is equivalent to

$\displaystyle \int F.dr$ where $C$ is the portion of the curve $x^2 + z^2 = 2$, forming an outer boundary to the surface.

So, in the Line Integral $dy= 0$, and  taking $x = \sqrt{2}\cos\theta$ ,$y = \sqrt{2}\sin\theta$,

I get my integral as :

$\displaystyle \int (-2 \cos\theta\sin \theta + 2\sin\theta\cos \theta)d \theta$, giving me the answer $0$.

However the answer given is $24 \pi$

I cannot understand where am I wrong in my solution ?

Can anyone please help me here ?

Comment: Note that you want the flux of $\vec F$, not the flux of $\text{curl }\vec F$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Yes I understood my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Stokes theorem you may evaluate the flux through the disc $x^2+z^2\leq 2$ in the plane $y=6$. Such disc $D$ has the same outer boundary as the given surface $S$, but the flux is much simpler to compute.
Thus we find
$$\iint_D (-x,2y,z)\cdot (0,1,0)dS=\iint_D 2ydS=2\cdot 6\cdot |D|=12\cdot\sqrt{2}^2\pi=24\pi.$$

P.S. According to your approach, in the line integral you should use a vector field $G$ such that $\nabla\times G=F$.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer but can you tell me what is wrong with my solution ? and why does it fail to give the correct answer ?

Comment: First of all in the line integral you should use a vector field whose $G$ such that $\nabla \times G=F$. Moreover  the curve is $x=\sqrt{2}\cos\theta$, $y=6$ and $z= \sqrt{2}\sin\theta$

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I was so stupid to miss this. Thank you.